# Xamarin account does not include support for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: android

when I create a new app in visual studion 2012 I got the following error.

xamarin account does not include support for visual studio 2012. please download and install visual studio 2015, which include xamarin support for all

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin is only free in Visual Studio 2015 and later.